# How to get length of the longest prefix in Trie in C

Tags: c, pseudocode, prefix, trie

I'm trying to figure out how to find the length of the longest prefix of two words in Trie. I was trying to find a solution, but I found nothing.

I already have an implementation of Trie, where the nodes are represent by structure:

```
struct node
{
    int end;    // 1 if node is end of word or 0 if not
    int count;  // The number of words that contain current node
    struct node *letter[26]; // Array of nodes, which represent the alphabet
};

int length_of_longest_prefix(struct node *root)
{
   //??????????
}
```

I tried to make a recursive function for this problem, but I could not do it.

Let´s think about this filled trie:
[Filled trie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz3RF.png)

What is the best way to solve this problem?
Pseudocode will be very usefull.

My function:

```
//Global variable
  int total_max;

//root = start
int length_of_longest_prefix(struct node *root, struct node *start)
{
    int max = 0;
    int depth = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if(root->letter[i] != NULL && root->letter[i]->count >= 2)
        {
            depth = length_of_longest_prefix(root->letter[i], start);
            depth++;

            if(root->letter[i] == start->letter[i])
            {
                depth = 0;
            }
        }

        if(depth > total_max)
            total_max = depth;
    }
        return depth;
}

    int main(void)
    {
     total_max = 0;
     struct node *root = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

     for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
     {
        root->letter[i] = NULL;
     }

     root->end = 0;
     root->count = 0;

    /*Inserting strings to Trie*/

     length_of_longest_prefix(root, root);
     printf("%d\n", total_max);

     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: You don't need a global total max. Instead, save the value you've found in max and return max. Move the if depth check inside the if that actually sets the depth. I don't see why you need to pass start and the start check, but otherwise looks OK assuming prefix length doesn't include the current node, else the initial value for depth should be 1.

Comment: You have a prefix of at least 2 words if the current node has more than 1 child (the parents are also prefixes but they aren't as long so they don't matter). The longest one of those is just the one that's the furthest from the root node (has the largest depth/height).